# NSUserDefault not able to retrieve value double

Tags: ios, double, nsuserdefaults

I'm creating a simple double value, saving it as NSUserDefault and trying to recover it...but it doesn't.

```
- (IBAction)try:(id)sender {

    double value = 42.00;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setDouble:value forKey:@"kDoubleKey"];
   // NSLog(@"loading %f",myDouble);
}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSUserDefaults *fetchDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    double intValue = [fetchDefaults doubleForKey:@"kDoubleKey"];
    NSLog(@"douvle retrieve %f",intValue);
}
```

Comment: You are not clear. What do you get in the log in `viewWillAppear:`? Have you verified that `try:` is called? Are you killing and restarting the app right after `try:` is called?

Comment: Yeah, I'm killing the application and then want to recover the value.

Comment: That's the problem. You are killing the app before the `NSUserDefaults` are actually persisted to disk. Either call `synchronize` after setting the value or wait a minute before killing the app.

Comment: yeah, synchronize worked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to synchronise whenever you save something to the defaults:
put this at the end of your try method

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

Here is what apple says about this: *Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes.*

Comment: BTW - this isn't normally needed. The defaults get synchronized automatically after a delay. This is only needed if the app is killed before the defaults are auto synchronized.

Comment: Yes, but in this case I think the problem is that the app exits before defaults are synced. The declaration of the defaults and the retrieval seems fine.